# Does removing the "final" keyword affect binary compatibility?

Tags: java, binary-compatibility

If I remove the `final` keyword from a method or other "thing", will users of my class have to recompile?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I want to remove it, not add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, they won't have to recompile.

I cannot think of any repercussions that can result from removing the final keyword from a method / attribute which may lead to loss in compatibility so it should not give you any problems.

Tested with sample code and there were no runtime errors:

```
public class Test2{
    public static final String test = "HELLO!";
}

public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println(Test2.test);
    }
}
```

1. Compiled Test.java
2. Ran Test.java -> Output = "HELLO!"
3. Modified Test2.java:

   ```
   public class Test2{
       public static String test = "HELLO!";
   }
   ```
4. Compiled Test2.java
5. Ran Test.java -> Output = "HELLO!"

Answer (score 4):

No, removing the final keyword will not break compatibility assuming you're fine with this wart:

If module B calls any method from a class in module A and module C overrode the previously final method, and an object from module C is passed to module B, the call will go to module A's implementation.

Comment: Please note this particular wart should not be depended on to work either as any code relying on it is depending on a compiler optimization to function.

Answer (score 2):

No if your clients call your code directly. 
But is might break a program that discovers your class using reflection, checks whether your method is final and does different things if method is final or not.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the horse's mouth:

> Changing a method that is declared final to no longer be declared final does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.17